# How to use gwtbootstrap3 calendar with UiBinder

Tags: gwt, gwtbootstrap3

Can we use gwtbootstrap3 fullcalendar mentioned at http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#fullcalendar with UiBinder.

I am trying to use it with UiBinder and nothing is appearing on that page.

code to my UiBinder class

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
    xmlns:b="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.gwt">
    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="calendarContainer">
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

code to the corresponding view class

```
public class EventView extends ReverseCompositeView<IEventView.IEventPresenter> implements IEventView {

    private static EventViewUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create( EventViewUiBinder.class );

    interface EventViewUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, EventView> {
    }

    @UiField
    HTMLPanel calendarContainer;

    @Override
    public void createView() {
        //don't create the view before to take advantage of the lazy loading mechanism
        initializeCalendar();
        initWidget( uiBinder.createAndBindUi( this ) );
    }

    private void initializeCalendar() {
        final FullCalendar fc = new FullCalendar("event-calendar", ViewOption.month, true);
        fc.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onLoad(LoadEvent loadEvent) {
                addEvents();
            }

            private void addEvents() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                    Event calEvent = new Event("id "+ i, "this is event "+i);
                    int day = Random.nextInt(10);
                    Date start = new Date();
                    CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(start, -1 * day);
                    calEvent.setStart(start);
                    if(i%3 ==0){
                        calEvent.setAllDay(true);
                    }else{
                        Date d = new Date(start.getTime());
                        d.setHours(d.getHours()+1);
                        calEvent.setEnd(d);
                    }
                    fc.addEvent(calEvent);
                }
            }

        });

        calendarContainer.add(fc);
    }


}
```

and I am using `mvp4g` framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
initializeCalendar();
initWidget( uiBinder.createAndBindUi( this ) );
```

You should first init the widget and then initialize the calendar. This is because you are adding your `FullCalendar` to the `calendarContainer` `HTMLPanel` in `initializeCalendar`. And before the call to `initWidget`, `calendarContainer` is `null`.

I think you can go a step further and do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
    xmlns:b="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.gwt"
    xmlns:f="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.extras.fullcalendar">
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <f:FullCalendar ui:field="fullCalendar" />
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

And then in your `EventView`:

```
@UiField(provided = true) FullCalendar fullCalendar;
```

`@UiField(provided = true)` means it's up to you to initialize this widget *before* calling `initWidget`. So, in *this* case, the order:

```
initializeCalendar();
initWidget( uiBinder.createAndBindUi( this ) );
```

is OK. Additionally, you don't have to add the `FullCalendar` to any panel anymore - it's already added, you just have to initialize it.

Comment: You are awesome my friend, Is there any book or tutorial on gwtbootstrap3 or would you like to write one, I can also help.

Comment: Thank you :) The best "reference" I know is the [demo](http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/). I've learned most that way - and looking at the [demo's source code directly](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3-demo). As for writing a guide - I haven't felt the need to do so. GWT's documentation + gwtbootstrap3's demo has been enough for me, in most cases (in others, I browse the issues or just google it). But I understand that others would benefit from a more thorough resource.

Comment: cool and thank you again, I did not know about the demo source code this is going to be super helpful to me.